# Mockito and Assertions - two same BigDecimals... not equal

Tags: java, assert, bigdecimal

I have a small problem with Assertion, or maybe just with BigDecimal.

My JUnit test is throwing an error while using `assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual)`:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<10> but was:<10.000000000>
```

expected is created via:

```
BigDecimal expected = MathHelper.getDecimal(10);
```

The `getDecimal` method in `MathHelper` looks like this:

```
public static final BigDecimal getDecimal(long value) {
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
}
```

The `actual` is a `private BigDecimal count` and it's getter method is a classic getter:

```
public BigDecimal getCount() {
    return count;
}
```

I have absolutely no idea what is going on here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation of the `equals` method for `BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Compares this BigDecimal with the specified Object for equality. Unlike `compareTo`, this method considers two `BigDecimal` objects equal only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to 2.00 when compared by this method).

So no, `10` and `10.000000000` are not equeal, and the assertion error is correct.

Answer (score -1):

BigDecimal equals method takes into account scale of the number, so BigDecimals 12.0 and 12.00 are different. You should use Bigdecimal compareTo method.

Comment: compareTo is returning an int equal to -1, 1 or 0. I would love to know the information what were the expected and actual values, not just the information that they differ...